# Como selecionar colunas de texto no editor?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Eu estou editando alguns arquivos com o VS Code e preciso selecionar uma coluna inteira do arquivo.

Por exemplo:

```
Insert Into Tabela (Data, Nome) Values
(2017-07-05, 'Huginho')
(2017-08-08, 'Zezinho')
(2017-11-25, 'Luizinho')
(2017-12-12, 'Donald')
(2017-09-06, 'Margarida')
```

Eu quero selecionar todas as datas ao mesmo tempo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pressione <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> e selecione a área desejada.